# Perl: "Quantifier in {,} bigger than 32766 in regex"

Tags: regex, perl

Let's say I want to find in a large (300,000 letters) the word "dogs" with the distance between letters **exactly** 40,000 letters in between. So I do:

```
$mystring =~ m/d.{40000}o.{40000}g.{40000}s/;
```

This will work quite well in other (slower) languages but in Perl it throws me "Quantifier in {,} bigger than 32766 in regex".

So:

1. Can we use a bigger number as the quantifier somehow?
2. If not, is there another good way to find what I want? Note that "dogs" is only an example; I want to do this for any word and any jump size (and fast).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you really need to do this *fast* I would look at a custom search based on the ideas of [Boyer-Moore string search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string_search_algorithm).  A regular expression is parsed into a finite state machine.  Even a clever, compact representation of such a FSM is not going to be a very effective way to execute a search like you describe.

If you really want to continue along the lines you are now you can just concatenate two expressions like `.{30000}.{10000}` which is the same as `.{40000}` in practice.

Comment: Nice work-around. I considered writing something from scratch, but it's a little overkill for me since in practice the searches I'll run in the brute-force regex method will take only ten minutes or so which is acceptable for my uses.

Comment: @GadiA I would be curious if `study` would improve the performance of the match any.

Answer (score 5):

I think [index](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/index.html) might be better suited for this task. Something along the lines of the completely untested:

```
sub has_dogs {
    my $str = shift;
    my $start = 0

    while (-1 < (my $pos = index $$str, 'd', $start)) {
        no warnings 'uninitialized';
        if ( ('o' eq substr($$str, $pos +  40_000, 1)) and
             ('g' eq substr($$str, $pos +  80_000, 1)) and
             ('s' eq substr($$str, $pos + 120_000, 1)) ) {
             return 1;
         }
     }
     return;
 }
```

Answer (score 5):

40,000 = 2 * 20,000

```
/d(?:.{20000}){2}o(?:.{20000}){2}g(?:.{20000}){2}s/s
```

Comment: It's easy to do the above mechanically, so it satisfies your request for "any size". Secondly, you really want to use "s", otherwise /`.`/ means /`[^\n]`/ would be be *a lot* of needless checks.